# He couldn't hold his alcohol - how to say it in Russian?

Tags: idioms

I was trying to explain to someone the English phrase:

> He couldn't hold his alcohol (also liquor)

This means that one becomes drunk very easily. Are there any Russian idioms/expressions that are roughly equivalent?

Comment: The russian stereotype would have people believe that such a phrase is unnecessary...

Comment: To me "not being able to hold one's liquor" doesn't say anything about drunkenness, only about disposition towards vomiting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Его/её быстро "развозит".** - He becomes drunk very fast. (Here is allegory to dirt road under rain).

**Ему/ей и капли хватит напиться.** - One drop of alcohol, and he/she will be drunk.

**Слабенький попался. (Слабенькая попалась)** - Weak constitution human that easy affected to alcohol.

**Ему и пробочку понюхать хватит.** - Smell a cork - and he's done!

Answer (score 8):

There's a `не умеет пить` but it this is more with a stress on the fact that one behaves badly / inappropriately even when supposedly he/she hadn't drunk that much. Like in the following phrase (found in Internet):

> Муж не умеет пить. То есть если выпьет больше одного бокала, скажем,
>   вина или пива (водку не пьет), становится полным идиотом, дурачком и
>   мудаком.

A more neutral way would be to just say `быстро пьянеет` (or, more casual, `быстро напивается`) - getting drunk fast.

Answer (score 3):

> От одного запаха [спиртного] пьянеет.

Just throwing it there.